# How do I get midnight of current day in a specified timezone in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a server in New York, and a "client" in California which expects that server to figure out midnight of the current day in California, which is not the same as New York's for three hours out of the day.

I have only been able to calculate midnight for the current day as is seen by New York, but I need to be able to calculate midnight of the current day for California (or any other arbitrary timezone)

I do have access to the timezone's offset from UTC.

```
$tzOffset = "-700"; // Timezone offset from UTC (in this case, PDT)
```

The (semi-working) method that I'm using right now is

```
strtotime("00:00:00 " . $tzOffset);
```

On Jun 25 at 10:00 PM PDT, this method is returning Jun 26 at 12:00 AM PDT as midnight, when it should be returning Jun 25 12:00 AM PDT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// create time from string
$date_time = new Datetime('midnight', new Datetimezone('America/Los_Angeles'));
// string representation of time in America/Los_Angeles
echo $date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
$date_time->setTimezone(new Datetimezone('America/New_York'));
// string representation of the same time in America/New_York
echo $date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: I'm using jstimezone to solve the problem of how to get the timezone string [http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/)

Answer (score 0):

Create datetime object in one timezone

```
$dt = new Datetime('2014-06-25 00:00:00', new Datetimezone('America/New_York'));
```

Change it to another timezone

```
$dt->setTimezone(new Datetimezone('America/Los_Angeles'));
```